# Process substitution working in zsh but not is bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, process-substitution

I'm attempting to sign some content using a certificate with the following command which uses process substitution to deliver the certificate content to openssl (since it requires either a file or uri):

```bash
echo "something to sign" \
| openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign <(echo "certificate to sign with")
```

This runs flawlessly in zsh but when I try to run this via bash I get an error:

`Could not read private key from /dev/fd/63`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `=(...)` in zsh? See https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh for the difference.

Comment: @Barmar I am certain that I am running that command as it is in the question, and that 'echo $SHELL' is /bin/zsh

Comment: `echo $SHELL` does not tell you the currently running shell, it tells you your login shell.

Comment: @glennjackman right you are. However using 'ps -p $$' does indeed show that I am using zsh. Also this issue revolves around the process substitution not working correctly when run in bash.

Comment: Can't think of any reason why they would work differently. There are situations where `<(` may not work, and `=(` works around it in zsh. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was all due to new line `\n` sequences in the credentials payload and `echo` requiring interpretation of backslash escapes to be turned on when using `bash`.

```bash
echo "something to sign" \
| openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign <(echo -e "certificate to sign with")
```

When using `zsh` the backslashes are seemingly interpreted automatically making me believe the issue was with the process substitution but not the contents of the credentials.

It feels silly to not have realized this sooner, but I hope this will help someone in the future also gets lost in the weeds.

Comment: You can use `<(printf "certificate to sign with")' which works in both bash and zsh

Comment: Good suggestion @Philippe, it just requires slight addition `<(printf '%s' "certificate")` but does work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `openssl` doesn't like to read from a named pipe.  Named pipes can be used for implementing process substitution and operate like a FIFO that doesn't support `fseek()`.

More info here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/why-does-bash-process-substitution-not-work-with-some-commands

On my Linux system, both bash and zsh fail with `Could not read private key from /dev/fd/63`, and `Could not read private key from /proc/self/fd/12`, respectively.  But perhaps zsh implements process substitution another way on your machine.

The "Process Substitution" section of `man zshexpn` has more to say about the possible pitfalls of `<()`.  It also says that `=()` uses a temporary file instead of a named pipe, so it will work with programs that want to seek.  But Bash does not have `=()`.

Comment: Well if that is the case then it sure would be annoyingly inconsistent. I already knew about `=()` and this works fine along with `<()` but ofcourse only with `zsh`. Since the command is being run in a portable script then it has to be `bash`.